# Setting up a transparent proxy on Mac OS X

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, osx-mavericks

I have a proxy running that I can successfully use with both Firefox and Safari. However flash is less amiable and from what I read it will not use a system proxy unless if cannot connect directly. Is there a way on Mac OS X to force everything through a proxy. That is only allow the proxy access to the outside internet?

Edit:

Ran route this is what I got and then all internet stopped working even with the proxy running

```
Mac:~ user$ sudo route flush
Password:
default              xx.xx.xx.xx        done
route: write to routing socket: No such process
got only -1 for rlen
Mac:~ user$ sudo route add 127.0.0.1
route: writing to routing socket: Invalid argument
add host 127.0.0.1: Invalid argument
```

Then I launch TCPCatcher and run it on port 8200 with monitor SSL enabled and Transparent Proxy unchecked.

I then set my Proxy in System Preferences to 127.0.0.1:8200

After that I set firefox to use the System Proxy

I then attempt to connect to a website and it fails.

Comment: Doesn't sound like "transparent proxy" is the right name for something that needs to be configured everywhere…

Comment: Sorry I guess it might not be I am rather new to it sense I'm so use to having an option for a proxy in most software.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all default routes (using the `route` command) and add one specifically for the proxy's IP address.

Comment: So like this... (proxy running on 127.0.0.1:8200)

sudo route flush

sudo route add 127.0.0.1:8200

Comment: @Zimm3r: Routes are added to the IP address – and the :port isn't part of that.

Comment: So wouldn't say https and http try different ports both of which aren't the proxy.

Comment: Tried without the port and it still failed to work (not connecting to internet